# Does the article come before or after a numeral value?

Tags: articles, nombres, ordre-des-mots

I came to know that before French nouns we have to put article accordingly for (masculine/feminine/plural) But I'm stuck as where to put the article in the following sentence:

I have 5 red cars.

> J'ai des 5 voitures rouges.

or

> J'ai 5 des voitures rouges.

Which one is correct or are they both wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is grammatically wrong, the second one is a wrong translation.

The numeral removes the requirement for an article so that should be:

> J'ai cinq voitures rouges.

Variants would have a different meaning:

> J'ai les cinq voitures rouges.

I have the five red cars (There are exactly five red cars and they are all mine).

> J'ai cinq des voitures rouges.

I have five out of the red cars (There are more that five red cars, five of them are mine).

Comment: can you provide me the website /resource for learning  rules for no article before noun .

Comment: As a side note: for complementary info, when you are however using ordinal values, the article gets back into business. Example: I own the fifth car ==> la cinquième voiture m'appartient